# Dynamically choose query variables in React Apollo

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I'd like to be able to dynamically choose which query variables I use in GraphQL.

For example, it seems a little redundant to need three separate queries:

```
const getAllStops = gql`
  query trafficStops {
    trafficStops {
      id
      date
    }
  }
`

const getStopsAfter = gql`
  query trafficStops($after: String!) {
    trafficStops(after: $after) {
      id
      date
    }
  }
`
const getStopsBefore = gql`
  query trafficStops($before: String!) {
    trafficStops(before: $before) {
      id
      date
    }
  }
`
```

Is there a way in which I could pass not just the variables `before` or `after` but whether I'd like to use one, the other, neither, or both into a single query instead of having multiple queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just have to make your arguments optional. The exclamation mark at `String!` requires the argument to be a string and not null. Hence, by removing it you could write your single query as

```
const getAllStops = gql`
  query trafficStops($after: String, $before: String)  {
    trafficStops(after: $after, before: $before) {
      id
      date
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: You know, I'd had it set up this way on the server and it didn't even occur to me to do it on the frontend. Thanks!